# For Loop not running in ViewDidLoad - everything else is

Tags: swift, for-loop, mapkit, mkannotation, ckrecord

The download restaurant function returns 2, so it's not an issue of an empty array. However, as I try to take each value in the array and put it through my for loop to add an annotation to the map, nothing happens. No print statement, no annotations. I have a print statement in my current loop and it did not run, but I am unsure why it is not running.

I tried putting the for loop in its own function and placing it after the download fuction but no difference.

I'm including the entire code to best provide all the information regarding this issue

```
import UIKit
import CloudKit
import SafariServices
import MapKit
import GoogleMobileAds

class InterFood: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var myMap: MKMapView!

    var bannerView: GADBannerView!
    var restaurantArray: Array<CKRecord> = []
    var index: NSIndexPath!
    var pin: AnnotationPin!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print("Hi")

        self.myMap.delegate = self

        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title:"", style:.plain, target:nil, action:nil)

        func downloadRestaurants () {
            let publicDB = CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase
            let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
            let query = CKQuery(recordType: "InternationalCenter", predicate: predicate)

            query.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "Name", ascending: true)]

            publicDB.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil) { (results, error) -> Void in
                if (error != nil) {
                    print("Error" + (error?.localizedDescription)!)
                } else {
                    for result in results! {
                        self.restaurantArray.append(result)
                    }
                    OperationQueue.main.addOperation( { () -> Void in
                        self.myMap.reloadInputViews()
                        //   activityIndicator.isHidden = true
                        print("Downloading")
                        print(self.restaurantArray.count)
                    })
                }
            }
        }

        downloadRestaurants()

        print("Hi Again")

        self.title = "International Center"

        let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 42.722869, longitude: -84.488012)

        let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinate, 2000, 2000)

        myMap.setRegion(region, animated: true)

        for res in restaurantArray {
            pin = AnnotationPin(title: res.value(forKey: "Name") as! String, subtitle: "Address", theCoordinates: res.value(forKey: "Location") as! CLLocationCoordinate2D, theWeb: "https://google.com")

            myMap.addAnnotation(pin)

            self.myMap.reloadInputViews()
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried implementing this function described here but no success as our code is quite similar: [how to set up array for multi annotations with swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36666968/how-to-set-up-array-for-multi-annotations-with-swift)

[image]

Comment: This is the nature of asynchronous calls. Notice how "Hi Again" if printed before "Downloading".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the restaurantArray is empty when you iterate over it is because the query is performed asynchronously. `viewDidLoad()` will execute in it's entirety before your query returns results. You can see this in the output of your program. It prints "Hi Again" before "Downloading" even though you call `downloadRestaurants()` first.

Comment: How would you recommend I go about the issue? Being async, should I use a defer function for the query and have the for loop run afterwards?